# Photoshop duplicate layers keeping size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, resize

I'm trying to duplicate layers from a doc A4 to a A3 doc, but it resizes the layers. If a layer is 100x100, in the new is 200x200 or so. Is there a way to duplicate layer keeping its original size in the new doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would need more clarity...It seems as if you have different DPI settings, where one might be at 100DPI and the other at 200DPI, thus changing the layer size. If this is the case, adjust it in the menu to match; In the menu select "Image>Image Size" then adjust the resolution(DPI) accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that is, DPI. Thanks so much.